# Get URL Parameter with header php

Tags: php

I have an Login Form which is linked to **login.php**. In there, if the password is wrong I have this:

```
$msg = 'Password is wrong!';
header('Location: /index.php?msg='.$msg);
```

And this is processed by the **index.php** file:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['msg'])){
    $msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
    echo($msg);
}
```

When I use the url in the browser eg. `index.php?msg=test` it works completly fine but when I use the form, it only redirects to Site Root eg. `site.com` without the `index.php?msg=test`.

I hope my problem is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What form?  You posted no form data.

Comment: do a var_dump(__DIR__); in your login.php to see that your file path  is right. or try to redirect using ./index.php as header('Location: ./index.php?msg='.$msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are using single quote ('') instead of double quotes ("") inside your header() function...try change to this

```
header("Location: /index.php?msg=$msg");
```

Note: if login.php and index.php are in the same directory folder then you dont need the '/' which should be

```
header("Location: index.php?msg=$msg");
```

Comment: This is actually the exact same string. BTW: I would suggest to use `{}` in strings. `?msg={$msg}`. Ppl will then know what to do as soon they want to add array or object values into strings.